# Using SQL Server Express on localhost for a web application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-express

I created a web application that it should run in local and I don't need to transfer it to host, but when I try to run my web application on local I get this error :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Other projects that use SQL Server 2008 R2 run without any problem but this project that uses SQL Server Express shows this error.

Comment: Can you connect using SSMS? Do you use windows authorization or SQL Serer auth?

Comment: I don't install SQL Express on my machine but now i downloaded LocalDb from microsoft website and installed but again i got that error

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 R2 i use sql server authentication.

Comment: What is the connection string?

Comment: This is my connection string : <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source= (LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Charity-20151219074430.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Charity-20151219074430;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Try changing data source to  "Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb"

Comment: I changed to "Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb" but does not work :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99008/discussion-between-marko-juvancic-and-a-programmer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

```
Start Menu >
    Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 > 
        Configuration Tools > 
            SQL Server Configuration Manager
```

You should see a screen something like this:

[image]

If you have two instances running, there should be **two entries** on the right with "SQL Server (....)" and `State = running`. The values in the brackets is the **instance name** for each - what are does??

- `MSSQLSERVER` stands for the **default, unnamed** instance - you connect to it using `.`, `(local)` or the machine name alone
- `SQLEXPRESS` is the default for a SQL Server **Express** installation, and you connect to it using `.\SQLEXPRESS`, `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or `your-machine-name\SQLEXPRESS`
- If the instance name is anything else - that is your instance name which you need to use after the colon (`.`) or the `(local)` to connect to it locally

Comment: The remote procedure call failed.[0x800706be]